# retain HTML select option in jsp dilemma

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, html-select

I have a form with select input, and I want to retain the selected option after submit.

So far I have found 2 solutions:

**select1.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select 1</title>
  <script>
    function submitSelected1() {
      document.form1.selected.value = document.form1.item.selectedIndex;
      document.form1.submit();
    }
    function retainSelected1(selected) {
      if (selected) document.form1.item.selectedIndex = selected;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="retainSelected1(${param.selected})">
<form name="form1" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="post">
  <select name="item" onchange="submitSelected1()">
    <option selected disabled>-- select item --</option>
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2">Item2</option>
    <option value="3">Item3</option>
    <option value="4">Item4</option>
  </select>
  <input type="hidden" name="selected" value="">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**select2.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Select 2</title>
  <script>
    function retainSelected2(selected) {
      document.querySelectorAll('[name=form2] option[value="' + selected + '"]')[0].defaultSelected = true;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="retainSelected2(${param.item})">
<form name="form2" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/controller" method="post">
  <select name="item">
    <option selected disabled>-- select item --</option>
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2">Item2</option>
    <option value="3">Item3</option>
    <option value="4">Item4</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The question is in which one is better and why. I am also interested in if there are any better solutions to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage` to retain your values & have something stateful :

## On Submit :

- Save selected option value just before submit.

  ```
     sessionStorage.setItem('LAST_SELECTED',document.querySelectorAll('[name=form1] option[selected]')[0].value);
  ```

  ;

## On Page Load :

- Get the value of last selected option :

  ```
   var value=sessionStorage.getItem('LAST_SELECTED');
  ```

  _  Set Selected Option :

  ```
  document.querySelectorAll('[name=form1] option[value="'+value+'"]')[0].defaultSelected = true
  ```

---

Comment: In my case `option[selected]` selector will always give `-- select item --`. It should be replaced with `option:check`. Then it works.

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot. It seems that `sessionStorage` will keep everything on client side, thus it's definitely better than my first solution (since I don't need to send `selected` param with each request). And `querySelectorAll` removes loop through all options in my second solution. Thank you.

Comment: If it is a useful answer, plz, make question as resolved !